# verificando se a data de um EditText é maior que a data de outro EditText

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Tenho dois EditText no meu aplicativo e  seleciono a data usando um DatePicker preciso fazer com que o usuário não informe uma data menor que a informada no primeiro EditText.

Comment: Está a colocar a data que vem do `DatePicker` no `EditText` ? Como está o formato da data no primeiro `EditText` ?

Comment: Sim a data vem do DatePicker para o EditText o formato é dd-MM-yyyy para os dois EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que as datas dos dois `EditText` estão no formato `dd-MM-yyyy` pode fazer o seguinte:

```
EditText editData1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.meu_edit1); //id para o seu 1º EditText
EditText editData2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.meu_edit2); //id para o seu 2º EditText

//criar formato para interpretação da data
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

try {
    Date data1 = formato.parse(editData1.getText().toString()); //interpretar data1
    Date data2 = formato.parse(editData2.getText().toString()); //interpretar data2

    if (data2.getTime() < data1.getTime()){
        //código para quando segunda data é menor
    }
}
catch (ParseException ex){
    Log.d("Debug", "Um dos campos não tem uma data válida");
}
```

Utilizando os seguintes imports:

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```